# How to install paper_trail plugin on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm sure this is astonishingly straightforward, and I'm just inexperienced with Rails 3, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

I'm trying to install the [paper_trail](http://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) plugin into my Rails 3 app; but the instructions seem designed for Rails 2. I'm running under Windows, and don't have git available.

I've tried putting `gem 'paper_trail'` into my Gemfile and running `bundle install`, which picked up the gem correctly; but `rails generate paper_trail` (which I assume is the new form of `script/generate paper_trail` fails with `Could not find generator paper_trail.`

Can anyone give me some step-by-step instructions to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make this work by simply downloading the zipped code from github, unpacking it into vendor/plugins, installing the gem (through Gemfile and bundle install), and then copy-pasting the migration code in paper_trail's generator into a blank migration of the same name.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party. I am writing this since I found the thread through Google. Here is how I got it to work with Rail 3.0.9. I was getting the same error with

```
bundle exec rails generate paper_trail
```

as well as

```
bundle exec rails g paper_trail
```

and

```
rails generate paper_trail
```

Turns out, you need to run

```
bundle exec rails generate paper_trail:install
```

that generated the migration file for me and a

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

created the table.

Answer (score 2):

As of 11 October, `rails generate paper_trail` works as you would expect.